# Sharing Threads between processes?

Tags: c, unix

Can you use a pipe to share threads between two processes in C? I am writing my own shell and want to know if this implementation would be more optimal, if it is even possible?

Comment: "More optimal"? You mean, like, betterer than something that's already optimal?

Comment: No.  Each thread is inherently and inextricable tied to a single process.  Threads of one process can share *data* with threads of different processes via a pipe, but threads themselves are not data, and cannot be communicated over a pipe.

Comment: No. What does sharing a thread even mean? Have a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29)

Comment: If you are looking to share data between processes similar to how threads share data in common memory, maybe you look at shm_open(3) and mmap(2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each thread is specific to a process and share memory of the calling thread.

If you want efficient inter process communication, you can use shared memory.

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html

Comment: Or named pipes, or unnamed pipes, or a variety of [other IPC methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).